# Excel : Sum of values against DISTINCT values of corresponding column in the filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to have Sum of values in [C] against DISTINCT values of corresponding column [B] in the filter i.e. A

I tried SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C, (B:B)*(A:A=E2)))
also tried SUM(IF(Frequency)))

ending up getting 2900 instead of 3900 for USA.

[image]

Comment: For fun: `=REDUCE({"Country","Population"},UNIQUE(A2:A14),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,HSTACK(y,SUM(TAKE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:C,A:A=y)),,-1))))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
=SUM(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:C,A:A=E2)),0,3))
```

The idea is that you want to return all three columns to the Unique,  If you only return C it will remove the duplicate numbers even if they are attached to different cities.  Then use INDEX to return the 3 column.  One can also use `CHOOSECOLS`, but that is more typing.

```
=SUM(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:C,A:A=E2)),3))
```

Comment: I got 80 columns with 10K rows, I should use CHOOSECOLs right ?

Comment: either will work.  You would use choosecols if you are needing to sum multiple columns, but if your numbers are all in one just use index.

Comment: This is just sample data, your formula works perfectly ....however, I got too many columns between A & C which makes UNIQUE ineffective.....for ex in this case, im getting 6400

Comment: Then you need to be more specific in your example data.  This works for the question you asked.  Ask a new question that includes a better example of your data set.